# OpenCV cv2 image to PyGame image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pygame

```
def cvimage_to_pygame(image):
    """Convert cvimage into a pygame image"""
    return pygame.image.frombuffer(image.tostring(), image.shape[:2],
                                   "RGB")
```

The function takes a numpy array taken from the cv2 camera. When I display the returned pyGame image on a pyGame window, it appears in three broken images. I don't know why this is!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Heres what happens::

(Pygame on the left)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `shape` field width and height parameters are swapped. Replace argument:

```
image.shape[:2] # gives you (height, width) tuple
```

With

```
image.shape[1::-1] # gives you (width, height) tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

An other issue that i found : Colors are not right... This is because open cv images are in BGR (Blue Green Red) not in RGB ! so the right command is :

```
pygame.image.frombuffer(image.tostring(), image.shape[1::-1], "BGR")
```